# Amazon EC2 - How to run IIS on AWS configured Windows instances other than IIS/SQL Server Express AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Am I missing something here?

Amazons EC2 looks good and I'm trying to find a suitable AMI for a new Windows server I'm setting up.

I don't really want to use a community shared AMI from what I've seen so far, since the information you're presented with when selecting is limited and I presume there is a security risk with using images configured by other people.

Looking at the quick start AMI's, the only one that explicitly states that IIS is included is:

**Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server Express and IIS**

However... I want SQL Server Web Edition. I ran up a small instance of **Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server Web**, assuming this would have IIS, but this doesn't have IIS preinstalled. I attempted to add via "Add programs and features", but the process was not as I am used to and when I tried to run a simple test website I encountered the error like "Service WAS not running" (or similar).

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the base base AMI, and if IIS isn't there, you go into control panel and add it as a windows option...

If it struggles on the search for installation media, just google it and there is a way to do it (I have done this in the past).